# Looking for a node and graph based API

Tags: graphs

I am looking for an API that will allow me to create nodes and connections: Much like the Blueprint system in the Unreal Engine. I want to be able to create nodes and make connections between 'sockets'.
I'm looking for a .NET solution, and if the price is inexpensive enough, I'm open to purchasing it too.
I need this for a standalone .NET application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com). It's a graph database, open source (community edition is free) and it has an extensive REST API. It's very easy to get started with. The have very good documentation with lots of examples. There is a built in UI that lets you easily visualize graphs and create queries interactively. You can download and run it on your local machine for testing.

Here are the docs for the API: https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/

It has an API that you can use right out of the box. Here is an example of using the API to create a graph databas, populate and query it:  https://www.sitepoint.com/create-neo4j-graph-database-using-rest-api/

Comment: Good recommendation. It's unclear how much it costs. Do you happen to know?

Comment: Is this for WebAPI's only? I'm not looking for anything to do with webapi's or such.

Comment: It is a database - not a SQL database but a graph database. It has a lot of power and capabilities - one of which is a web API. However you do not need to use the web API, you can access it directly from C# or .NET like you would for any database. Here is how: https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/

Comment: @Mawg - Neo4j Community Edition can be used for free with your project: whether in the cloud or behind the firewall. If you want a big scalable installation with support (enterprise) they have paid options.